# How to run Windows 10 Certificate Export Wizard for local user certificate when the cert does not exist yet?

Tags: windows-10, certificate

All the instructions on how to export a local Windows 10 user certificate says to go to the Certificate Manager for the local users and go to:

Certificates - Current User => Personal => Certificates

[certmgr screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YezDr.png)

to find your cert and then you can export it.  But, I don't have any certs in this location.  I used the find function to search all cert stores for my currently logged-in username and came up with nothing.  So, I need some alternative instructions on how to run the Certificate Export Wizard.

Edit: I didn't previously install a cert.  I'm assuming that one is created for all Windows accounts and I simply want to back it up so I can access my encrypted files in case of a disaster.

Comment: How do you know you installed the certificate in the first place?  Anyways the certificate could be moved/installed to any one of those locations under Certificates

Comment: @Ramhound I updated my question to address yours.